# UnicodeDecodeError installing numpy with pip in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

This is the error that appears when I try to install `numpy`. I have had another problem but, I already fixed it installing Microsoft Visual C++ and upgrading `setuptools` and `pip`

> I have Windows 8.1; python 3.7.ob3 (64bits); and pip version 9.0.3

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\JUAN CARLOS>pip install numpy Collecting numpy   Using cached numpy-1.14.2.zip Installing collected packages: numpy   Running setup.py install for numpy ... error

Exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 34: invalid start byte During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run prefix=options.prefix_path, File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install **kwargs File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install spinner=spinner, File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline()) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str return s.decode('utf_8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 34: invalid start byte During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\commands\install.py", line 385, in run requirement_set.cleanup_files() File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 729, in cleanup_files req.remove_temporary_source() File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 977, in remove_temporary_source rmtree(self.source_dir) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call raise attempt.get() File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2]) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise raise value File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree onerror=rmtree_errorhandler) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\shutil.p y", line 507, in rmtree return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\shutil.p y", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info()) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler func(path) PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'C:\\Users\\JUANCA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ pip-build-uvqrzmgo\\numpy' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\commands\install.py", line 385, in run requirement_set.cleanup_files() File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\utils\build.py", line 38, in __exit__ self.cleanup() File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\utils\build.py", line 42, in cleanup rmtree(self.name) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call raise attempt.get() File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2]) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise raise value File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree onerror=rmtree_errorhandler) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\shutil.p y", line 507, in rmtree return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\shutil.p y", line 386, in _rmtree_unsafe _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\shutil.p y", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info()) File "c:\users\juan carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pac kages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler func(path) PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'C:\\Users\\JUANCA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ pip-build-uvqrzmgo\\numpy'
```

Comment: Why are you using unstable(beta) Python python 3.7.ob3?

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that before. I install the 3.6 version and I don't have that problem anymore. Thanks for your insight :)